# google cloud sql - sql_mode

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-sql

I am using Google Cloud SQL and need set sql_mode '' (empty) but Google Cloud doesnt allow me to do it.

So, what value is equal to empty?

[Cloud SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS6wU.png)

Comment: You can set [sql_mode flag](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#list-flags) in Cloud SQL. Except the options NO_DIR_IN_CREATE and NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION. You can read the options list [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-full). Which option would you like to set and what is the error message you are receiving?

Comment: I need set empty value but in GCP i can not...

Answer (score 0):

The default SQL mode is empty [[1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.5-en/sql-mode.html)]. If you have previously set a SQL mode you can remove the flag by using the Console [[2](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#config)]; editing the Cloud SQL instsance's configuration and removing the sql_mode flag.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot set sql_mode flag to empty** for Google Cloud SQL instance.
If you are looking to override the default behavior of this flag simply set it to something like **`ALLOW_INVALID_DATES`**

Comment: The same thing was pointed out in the comments of the question.